# Partial content video stream with node js to IOS

Tags: ios, node.js, iis, express, video-streaming

I am trying to get make a mp4 video file to stream to ios devices. I am using an IIS-server to catch https connection from domain and then reverse proxy to my express(nodejs) server on localhost. This is my node js:

```
    var range = req.headers.range;
    var contentType = _mime2.default.lookup(filename);

    if (req.get('Range') == null){
        console.log("hei");
        res.status(200);
        res.set('Connection', 'keep-alive');
        res.set('Content-Type',contentType);
        res.set('Content-Length', data.length);
        res.set("Accept-Ranges", "bytes");
      res.end(data)
    }else{
      var total = data.length;
      var split = range.split(/[-=]/);
      var ini = +split[1];
      var end = split[2]?+split[2]:total-1;
      var chunkSize = end - ini + 1;
     if (parseInt(ini) >= total || parseInt(end) >= total) {
       //Indicate the acceptable range.
        res.status(416);
        res.set("Content-Range",'bytes */' + total); // File size.
       //Return the 416 'Requested Range Not Satisfiable'.
         res.end();
     }
      res.status(206);
      res.set('Connection', 'keep-alive');
      res.set("Content-Range","bytes " + ini + "-" + end + "/" + total);
      res.set("Accept-Ranges", "bytes");
      res.set("Content-Length", chunkSize);
      res.set("Content-Type", contentType);
      res.end(data.slice(ini, chunkSize+ini));
    }
  }).catch(function (err) {
    res.status(404);
    res.set('Content-Type', 'text/plain');
    res.end('File not found.');
  });
```

[![Catched with firefox][1]][1]

Behaviour on different browsers:

- Chrome downloads the whole video
- Firefox plays the video fine
- OSX safari downloads the whole video
- IOS safari won't start playing/streaming

Anyone know why IOS safari don't like this?

(video: format: h.264, 568x320, AAC, 22050 hz, 784.65 kbit/s, .mp4)

Comment: can you share the iOS code how you are sending the data to the server?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The response `Content-Type` is incorrect. It should be `video/mp4`. Also, it's not clear where your `data` variable is coming from, but you should probably be doing something like this instead:

```
res.status(206);
res.set('Connection', 'keep-alive');
res.set("Content-Range","bytes " + ini + "-" + end + "/" + total);
res.set("Accept-Ranges", "bytes");
res.set("Content-Length", chunkSize);
res.set("Content-Type", contentType);
fs.createReadStream(filename, { start: ini, end: end }).pipe(res)
```

You shouldn't need to have the entire file buffer in memory. Aside from that you might also need to handle multiple byte ranges in the same request. Where the request `Range` header has a value like `0-9,50-499,1000-`. In those cases you'd need to respond with a `multipart/byteranges` response.

Comment: Thanks for reading through and pointing me in the right direction! Not found solution just yet, but I do have a mongodb and the data is a gridfile (I think). I am new to this so I have to search around a bit more, I will come back with more information.

Comment: [leroib from weightingformypizza](https://weightingformypizza.wordpress.com/2015/06/24/stream-html5-media-content-like-video-audio-from-mongodb-using-express-and-gridstore/) was the solution for me.  [The work is licensed under a Creative Commons Attribution 4.0 International License.](http://creativecommons.org/licenses/by/4.0/). Thanks idbehold for pointing me in the right direction.  (It didn't work on https, but on http, so that is an IIS-server issue with TLS 1.2 protocol I think)